# Django's CsrfViewMiddleware fails in conjunction with response generated by middleware

Tags: django

My Django application is using a middleware stack containing the CsrfViewMiddleware and an own middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
'myapp.OwnMiddleware'
)
```

The basic idea is that if an URL can't be found, i.e. no view function is being found, this error is caught by `OwnMiddleware.process_response()` which returns an own response if the HTTP status is 404 (and some other conditions are being met).

This works fine, with a single problem: Because no view function is called when an invalid URL (according to URLconf) is provided, `CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view()` is never called, and thus no CSRF cookie is generated.

Therefore the whole CSRF system does not work and the CSRF token is still set to "NOTPROVIDED" in `OwnMiddleware.process_response` (which means that {% csrf_token %} generates an empty string instead of the usual hidden form field).

What is the best way to solve this problem, i.e. have OwnMiddleware catch 404s and return another (non-404) response, while still being able to use the CSRF token in these responses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually run something like:

```
CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view(request, lambda: your_response, [], {})
```

P.S. I think it's better to use [handler404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#handler404) to catch 404's

Comment: Just one comment, I just tried to use handler404 and it works nice for DEBUG=False, however it's disabled when DEBUG=True (then only the default 404 handler is called). Therefore it's of no real use if one wants to add functionality for 404s that must be tested.